# I can't send requests to the Telegram API

Tags: python-requests, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

I am implementing the function of setting the bot's response to a user's message (a new version of the bot api was recently released in Telegram, where this function appeared).

```
def send_react(message):
    global TOKEN
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    message_id = message.message_id
    reaction = ''
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/setMessageReaction'
    data = {
        'chat_id': chat_id,
        'message_id': message_id,
        'reaction': reaction,
        'is_big': False
    }
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        result = response.json()
        if result['ok']:
            print('ok')
        else:
            print('not ok:', result['description'])
    else:
        print('error:', response.status_code)
    return
```

However, I get an error: Error: 400 What could it be?

I also checked that when deleting the reaction and is_big fields, the request is successful, but in this case, the function is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is that the `reaction` of [`setMessageReaction`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmessagereaction) does expect an array of objects of type [`ReactionType`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#reactiontype) rather than a simple string. So you should define

```py
reaction = [{"type": "emoji", "emoji": ""}]
```

Telegram does provide a error message that helps to find this issue as part of the `response`. If you print `response.json()` in the exception as case as well, you'll see the info

> {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': "Bad Request: can't parse reaction types JSON object"}

Moreover, let me point out that you avoid the use of a global variable for the token by using `message.get_bot().token` - see [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.telegramobject.html#telegram.TelegramObject.get_bot) and [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.token) for docs on this.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.